# Ubuntu 19.10 .. can't change shell to zsh

Tags: shell, ubuntu, zsh

I'm trying various things but I can't change shell to zsh in Ubuntu 19.10 x64 on my MacBook Pro 2012 with 16 GB RAM.

`$ which zsh` # Output: /usr/bin/zsh
`$ zsh --version` # Output: zsh 5.7.1 (x86_64-ubuntu-linux-gnu)

`$ chsh -s $(which zsh)`
It makes changes to `/etc/passwd` file but when I run
`$ echo $SHELL`
It still gives me `/bin/bash`.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to do something to run a new login shell. Logging out and back in, for example.

Comment: The value of `SHELL` is just a variable in the current shell session; `chsh` does not (and cannot) change its value.

Comment: @ShahIsmail : Even after logging out and logging in again, the shell is still bash?

Comment: I was opening a new tab of the shell in Terminal but it wasn't working so I logged out and logged back in then it worked.
Unwillingly, I moved root shell to zsh but now I'm trying to move root shell back to bash but it is now stuck at zsh even after rebooting.